# magento ship to billing address only for first time buyers

Tags: magento

Does anybody know if this is possible, or how I would go about it. My client wants first time buyers to be limited to shipping to the billing address only, thereafter being able to get items shipped anywhere. I think it's a reasonably common thing in eCommerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but it would take a bit of work to do. You'd need to modify the account pages that let users add addresses, and the checkout page templates (probably just the /template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml page for the radio control that says 'Ship to this address'/'Ship to different address').

I'd do a check to see if a customer is logged in, see how many previous orders they have, and if they have a previous order then display the options to let them change their shipping address.